# Correct implementation of overlapping pads in

Tags: eaglecad, footprint

I want to use a 3 terminal capacitor, whose land pattern is described on page 9 [of the datasheet](http://search.murata.co.jp/Ceramy/image/img/A01X/G101/ENG/NFM21PC475B1A3-01.pdf)

I try to replicate it with overlapping SMD and through-hole pads.

[image]
According to PCB manufacturer's DR, the minimum restring is 0.2 mm and drill 0.3mm, that is why I am forced to make through holepads slightly larger (with 0.3mm drill). I disabled stop mask on all middle pads and drew with a polygon.

Is it the right path, or there is a better way?

Comment: what's a restring?

Comment: @Neil_UK https://www.element14.com/community/community/experts/blog/2012/03/02/eagle--what-are-the-restring-settings-in-the-design-rules-for